# Segmentation fault with deferred functions and non_overridable keyword

Tags: oop, fortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

I am developing an object-oriented Fortran code for numerical optimization with polymorphism supported by abstract types. Because it is a good TDD practice, I'm trying to write all optimization tests in the abstract type `class(generic_optimizer)`, which then should be run by each instantiated class, e.g., by `type(newton_raphson)`.

All the optimization tests feature a call to `call my_problem%solve(...)`, which is defined as `deferred` in the abstract type and of course features a different implementation in each derived type.

The issue is: if in each non-abstract class I define the deferred function as `non_overridable`, I get segmentation fault such as:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000913efe in __newton_raphson_MOD_nr_solve ()
#2  0x00000000008cfafa in MAIN__ ()
#3  0x00000000008cfb2b in main ()
#4  0x0000003a3c81ed5d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00000000004048f9 in _start ()
```

After some trial-and-error, I've noticed that I can avoid the error if I remove the `non_overridable` declaration. In this case it is not an issue, but I wanted to enforce that since two levels of polymorphism are unlikely for this code. Was I violating any requirements from the standard, instead?

Here is a sample code that reproduces the error. I've been testing it with gfortran 5.3.0 and 6.1.0.

```
module generic_type_module
    implicit none
    private

    type, abstract, public :: generic_type
        real(8) :: some_data
        contains
        procedure (sqrt_interface), deferred :: square_root
        procedure, non_overridable           :: sqrt_test
    end type generic_type

    abstract interface
       real(8) function sqrt_interface(this,x) result(sqrtx)
          import generic_type
          class(generic_type), intent(in) :: this
          real(8), intent(in) :: x
       end function sqrt_interface
    end interface

    contains

    subroutine sqrt_test(this,x)
        class(generic_type), intent(in) :: this
        real(8), intent(in) :: x
        print *, 'sqrt(',x,') = ',this%square_root(x)
    end subroutine sqrt_test

end module generic_type_module

module actual_types_module
    use generic_type_module
    implicit none
    private

    type, public, extends(generic_type) :: crashing
       real(8) :: other_data
       contains
       procedure, non_overridable :: square_root => crashing_square_root
    end type crashing
    type, public, extends(generic_type) :: working
       real(8) :: other_data
       contains
       procedure :: square_root => working_square_root
    end type working

    contains

    real(8) function crashing_square_root(this,x) result(sqrtx)
       class(crashing), intent(in) :: this
       real(8), intent(in) :: x
       sqrtx = sqrt(x)
    end function crashing_square_root
    real(8) function working_square_root(this,x) result(sqrtx)
       class(working), intent(in) :: this
       real(8), intent(in) :: x
       sqrtx = sqrt(x)
    end function working_square_root

end module actual_types_module

program deferred_test
    use actual_types_module
    implicit none
    type(crashing) :: crashes
    type(working)  :: works

    call works%sqrt_test(2.0_8)
    call crashes%sqrt_test(2.0_8)

end program
```

Comment: From a quick look, there is no obvious reason why the `non_overridable` attribute is prohibited (and no later attempt to override).  I don't have access to a compiler to reproduce the problem, though.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: What has this got to do with Deferreds?

Comment: Please don't use `real(8)` in otherwise nicely written code, it is really ugly. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201611092148501729426

Comment: I can replicate the problem. The code is calling a null-pointer instead of the correct procedure.

Comment: Thank you guys for your opinions - it looks like it's a secondary issue then, but do you think I should open a ticket on GCC bugzilla?

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down the problem, I removed the abstract attribute and data members from the OP's code such that

```
module types
    implicit none

    type :: Type1
    contains
        procedure :: test
        procedure :: square => Type1_square
    endtype

    type, extends(Type1) :: Type2
    contains
       procedure, non_overridable :: square => Type2_square
    endtype

contains

    subroutine test( this, x )
        class(Type1) :: this
        real :: x
        print *, "square(", x, ") = ",this % square( x )
    end subroutine

    function Type1_square( this, x ) result( y )
       class(Type1) :: this
       real :: x, y
       y = -100      ! dummy
    end function

    function Type2_square( this, x ) result( y )
       class(Type2) :: this
       real :: x, y
       y = x**2
    end function

end module

program main
    use types
    implicit none
    type(Type1) :: t1
    type(Type2) :: t2

    call t1 % test( 2.0 )
    call t2 % test( 2.0 )
end program
```

With this code, gfortran-6 gives

```
square(   2.00000000     ) =   -100.000000
square(   2.00000000     ) =   -100.000000
```

while ifort-{14,16} and Oracle fortran 12.5 give

```
square(   2.000000     ) =   -100.0000    
square(   2.000000     ) =    4.000000
```

I also tried replacing the functions with subroutines (to print which routines are actually called):

```
    subroutine test( this, x )
        class(Type1) :: this
        real :: x, y
        call this % square( x, y )
        print *, "square(", x, ") = ", y
    end subroutine

    subroutine Type1_square( this, x, y )
        class(Type1) :: this
        real :: x, y
        print *, "Type1_square:"
        y = -100      ! dummy
    end subroutine

    subroutine Type2_square( this, x, y )
        class(Type2) :: this
        real :: x, y
        print *, "Type2_square:"
        y = x**2
    end subroutine
```

with all the other parts kept the same. Then, gfortran-6 gives

```
Type1_square:
square(   2.00000000     ) =   -100.000000    
Type1_square:
square(   2.00000000     ) =   -100.000000
```

while ifort-{14,16} and Oracle fortran 12.5 give

```
Type1_square:
square(   2.000000     ) =   -100.0000    
Type2_square:
square(   2.000000     ) =    4.000000
```

If I remove `non_overridable` from the above codes, gfortran gives the same result as the other compilers. So, this may be a specific issue to gfortran + `non_overridable` (if the above code is standard-conforming)...

(The reason why OP got segmentation fault may be that gfortran accessed the `deferred` procedure in the parent type (`generic_type`) having null pointer; if this is the case, the story becomes consistent.)

---

**Edit**

The same exceptional behavior of gfortran occurs also when we declare Type1 as `abstract`. Specifically, if we change the definition of Type1 as

```
    type, abstract :: Type1    ! now an abstract type (cannot be instantiated)
    contains
        procedure :: test
        procedure :: square => Type1_square
    endtype
```

and the main program as

```
program main
    use types
    implicit none
    type(Type2) :: t2

    call t2 % test( 2.0 )
end program
```

we get

```
ifort-16    : square(   2.000000     ) =    4.000000    
oracle-12.5 : square( 2.0 ) =  4.0
gfortran-6  : square(   2.00000000     ) =   -100.000000
```

If we further make `square()` in Type1 to be `deferred` (i.e., no implementation given) and so make the code almost equivalent to the OP's case,

```
type, abstract :: Type1  ! now an abstract type (cannot be instantiated)
contains
    procedure :: test
    procedure(Type1_square), deferred :: square  ! has no implementation yet
endtype

abstract interface
    function Type1_square( this, x ) result( y )
        import
        class(Type1) :: this
        real :: x, y
    end function
end interface
```

then ifort-16 and Oracle-12.5 gives 4.0 with `call t2 % test( 2.0 )`, while gfortran-6 results in segmentation fault. Indeed, if we compile as

```
$ gfortran -fsanitize=address test.f90   # on Linux x86_64
```

we get

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV    (<-- or "ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL" on OSX 10.9)
=================================================================
==22045==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 
                (pc 0x000000000000 bp 0x7fff1d23ecd0 sp 0x7fff1d23eac8 T0)
==22045==Hint: pc points to the zero page.
```

So overall, it seems as if the binding name `square()` in Type1 (which has no implementation) is called erroneously by gfortran (possibly with null pointer). And more importantly, if we drop `non_overridable` from the definition of Type2, gfortran also gives 4.0 (with no segmentation fault).

Comment: very interesting @roygvib, thanks! Looks like gfortran assumes the parent routine is called even when non_overridable is specified from an extended type, then. Reading "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf, Reid, Cohen, I found:
- If the `non_overridable` attribute appears, that type-bound procedure cannot be overridden during type extension;
- `non_overridable` is incompatible with `deferred`, since that requires the type-bound procedure to be overridden;
- Overriding a type-bound procedure is not permitted if the inherited one has the `non_overridable` attribute.

Comment: Hi, I have considered your original code again, but it still looks to me that your code is correct... My understanding is that, regardless of whether we attach `non_overridable` to a type-bound procedure of Type2, its implementation (i.e., Type2_square) should be called from an instance of Type2. (My understanding is that `non_overridable` prohibits square() to be overwritten by a child type of Type2 (say Type3), so it has no effect on the behavior of Type2 itself.)

Comment: As for the sentence "`non_overridable` is incompatible with `deferred`" in Chap.14.6.1 of "Modern Fortran Explained" (I bought the Kindle version :), I guess this means that we cannot write something like `procedure(...), deferred, non_overridable :: square`, i.e., we cannot specify the two keywords at the same time. On the other hand, it is probably OK to use `procedure(...), deferred :: square` for Type1 and `procedure, non_overridable :: square => Type2_square` for Type2 (probably...).

Comment: So, if the above interpretation seems reasonable, I would really appreciate if you open a ticket on GCC bugzilla (I guess +4 upvotes on your question implies "go ahead"). It may be also very useful to ask opinions in [comp.lang.fortran](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.fortran), because there are many such threads (whether some code is standard-conforming, or a bug of codes or compilers).

Comment: thanks @roygvib, I've opened a ticket on GCC Bugzilla. Cheers!